# Switch toggle between time format (am/pm and 24H) from settings page

Tags: flutter

i want to have switch widget in settings page. i can figured switching theme using switch widget, but this is too complicated

my main_page:

```js
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Text("Summary"),
    ),

    SizedBox(height: 45),
    
    _time24(snapshot),  //show this if switch is off
    _time12(snapshot),  //show this if switch is on
    
  ],
)

Widget _time12(AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      _time(Icons.home, Text(DateFormat("hh:mma").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.home)))),
      _time(Icons.work, Text(DateFormat("hh:mma").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.work)))),
      _time(Icons.restaurant, Text(DateFormat("hh:mma").format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.restaurant)))),
    ]);
}
  
Widget _time24(AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    _time(Icons.home, Text(snapshot.data.home)),
    _time(Icons.work, Text(snapshot.data.work)),
    _time(Icons.restaurant, Text(snapshot.data.restaurant)),
  ]);
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can `await Navigator.push` then call `setState()`

code snippet

```
 onPressed: () async {
          await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Setting()),
          );
          setState(() {});
        }
 ...            
 else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (is24) {
                    return _time24(snapshot);
                  } else {
                    return _time12(snapshot);
                  }
                }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class Payload {
  String home;
  String work;
  String restaurant;

  Payload({this.home, this.work, this.restaurant});
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Future _future;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Widget _time12(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    var a = DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.home);
    print("a ${a}");
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      _time(
          Icons.home,
          Text(DateFormat("hh:mma")
              .format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.home)))),
      _time(
          Icons.work,
          Text(DateFormat("hh:mma")
              .format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.work)))),
      _time(
          Icons.restaurant,
          Text(DateFormat("hh:mma")
              .format(DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(snapshot.data.restaurant)))),
    ]);
  }

  Widget _time24(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      _time(Icons.home, Text(snapshot.data.home)),
      _time(Icons.work, Text(snapshot.data.work)),
      _time(Icons.restaurant, Text(snapshot.data.restaurant)),
    ]);
  }

  Widget _time(IconData iconData, Text _text) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(iconData),
      title: _text,
    );
  }

  Future<Payload> getData() {
    print("getData");
    return Future.value(
        Payload(home: "18:00", restaurant: "13:00", work: "08:00"));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _future = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<Payload>(
              future: _future,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Payload> snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                    return Text('Press button to start.');
                  case ConnectionState.active:
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Text('Awaiting result...');
                  case ConnectionState.done:
                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (is24) {
                        return _time24(snapshot);
                      } else {
                        return _time12(snapshot);
                      }
                    }
                }
                return null; // unreachable
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Setting()),
          );
          setState(() {});
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

bool is24 = true;

class Setting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingState createState() => _SettingState();
}

class _SettingState extends State<Setting> {
  void _changed(value) {
    setState(() {
      is24 = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Switch(
          value: is24,
          onChanged: _changed,
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works!! but is there any way i can seperate setting's page to another dart file? i tried couple things but the data wont pass to the main file. edit: also when i close the app the setting resets back to 24-hour

Comment: question 1: just move class to another file and import it , you do not need to pass it. question 2: you can save it with https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences